# How to pass changes in CustomCell data from didSelectRowAtIndexPath to heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to get the cell to collapse if it was already expanded.  This code is expanding the row when clicked, but the `bool cell.cell_expanded` is always FALSE in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.  I've tried `[tableView reloadData]` but that didn't do the trick.  Any idea?

I read that using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` can have a huge impact against performance, so if possible I would like to remove this method call.  Is it possible to refactor this functionality elsewhere?

Here's what I've got:

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImageView *cell_arrow;
    BOOL cell_expanded;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *cell_arrow;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL cell_expanded;
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *arrow = nil;
    if (cell.cell_expanded == TRUE) {
        arrow = @"arrow_down.png";
        cell.cell_expanded = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        arrow = @"arrow_up.png"; 
        cell.cell_expanded = TRUE;
    }
    cell.cell_arrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrow];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (selectedCellIndexPath != nil) {
        if (indexPath.row == selectedCellIndexPath.row) {
            NSLog(@"cell_expanded = %d for row %i", cell.cell_expanded, indexPath.row);
            CGSize theSize = [cell.cell_body.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, 9999.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            if (cell.cell_expanded == TRUE) {
                NSLog(@"open it");
                return theSize.height + 16;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"close it");
                return 44;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 44;
        }
    }
    return 44;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, a couple of things here:

1) Just call -reloadData instead of -end/beginUpdates.
2) You obviously didn't really understand how an UITableView works. UITableView reuses its cell. This means that you probably have like 5 cell instances. You should probably read the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about it. To solve your problem you should save the expanded variable in the instance variable represented by the UITableView.